# XslCompiledTransform exception when using Altova MapForce-generated XSLT file

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xslcompiledtransform, altova

I'm using .NET's XslCompiledTransform to perform an XSLT transformation. When I try using an XSLT file I've automatically generated using Altova's MapForce tool, I get the exception:

```
XSL conversion is failed: Cannot find the script or external object that implements prefix 'http://www.altova.com/xslt-extensions'.
```

From the XSL Stylesheet definition:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... xmlns:ns0="http://www.altova.com/xslt-extensions" ... >
```

...it seems that Altova defines its own extension functions to XSLT, and the XslCompiledTransform  doesn't know how to find them. How can I make the XslCompiledTransform recognize those external functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually extensions are not portable, only some EXSLT extensions like `exsl:node-set` are supported by a wide range of XSLT 1.0 processors, including XslCompiledTransform. If you develop with XML Spy and want to execute its stylesheets with .NET code then you can consider to use [AltovaXML](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html) with .NET, see http://manual.altova.com/AltovaXML/altovaxmlcommunity/index.html?axnetinterface.htm, instead of using XslCompiledTransform.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any details of Mapforce, but I do know that people successfully run Mapforce generated stylesheets with Saxon. Perhaps (I'm speculating) if you ask mapforce to generate a 2.0 stylesheet, then it won't need any Altova extensions, and you can then run the stylesheet with a 2.0 processor such as Saxon or XmlPrime.

(Incidentally, Microsoft have made it quite clear that they aren't planning to upgrade XsltCompiledTransform to XSLT 2.0, so you are using a dead-end technology. Saxon, Altova, and XmlPrime are all moving forward; Saxon and XmlPrime not only support XSLT 2.0 but large chunks of 3.0 as well. There are an awful lot of productivity benefits you are missing out on.)